# Как передавать данные из MediaStream потока через websocket?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, websocket, онлайн-трансляция

Хочу попробовать реализовать что-то типо discord или skype, где будет возможность звонков, видеозвонков и демонстрации экрана. Это будет web-приложение, т.е. работать оно будет в браузере

**Зачем мне это, ведь такие приложения уже есть?**
Я хочу узнать как это работает и получить опыт в создании таких платформ

**Почему я не хочу использовать готовые фреймворки по типу flashphoner?** Я хочу понять как это работает под капотом и уметь делать так же без фреймворков

**Что бы я хотел видеть в ответе?**
Я разобрался с тем, как получить данные с устройства клиента. Вопрос в том, как упаковать эти данные, чтобы я смог отправить их в формате json? И как распаковать потом эти же данные получив на стороне другого получив тот же `MediaStream` интерфейс? Backend сервер является только посредником, который передаёт данные и больше ничего не делает

Comment: для работы с камерой и микрофоно можно `WebRTC` юзать

Comment: Вопрос слишком большой и общий. В нем 5 больших вопросов. Начните как обычно - по шагам. С самого простого, потом наращивайте сложность. Начните с получения данных с микрофона в браузере, потом отправьте на сервер, потом попробуйте эти данные считать. И так с каждым вашим вопросом. В данном виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать полный ответ.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko с получением данных я ещё как-нибудь разберусь, но как передать эти данные? Данные возвращаются в виде "интерфейса" (если верить документации) `MediaStreamTrack`. Я же не могу передать это через websocket, как привести к json виду, а потом сделать обратно картинку и видео?

Comment: @AndreyFreiz понять бы ещё как его юзать...

Comment: @Inventor вот такие вопросы и надо задавать. Создайте вопрос, напишите туда пример кода в браузере, для получения данных с микрофона. Опишите ваш бакенд\сервер. Опишите, что вы хотите сделать с данными(отправить, обработать на сервере, отправить другому пользователю). И задайте вопрос. Ответ найдется быстро и это будет хороший вопрос.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko что вы мне предлагаете написать в примере кода? `MediaDevices.getUserMedia`? Больше я не знаю что писать. Код сервера никак не влияет на это, он просто посредник, реализация который ничего не обрабатывает, а пересылает данные (это понятно из вопроса). Сейчас уберу из вопроса подвопросы про получение данных с устройств пользователя, т.к. с этим разобрался

Comment: @Inventor, _MediaDevices.getUserMedia_ - ты не можешь так написать - потому что это так не работает

Comment: @Grundy окей, ты прав, `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

Comment: Собственно результат можно использовать с [WebRTC API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Те кто предлагают использовать мне WebRTC видимо не знают, что этот стандарт работает поверх протокола IP или UDP, но только не http и не websocket.

**Решением** моей задачи был этот пост: https://habr.com/ru/post/461769/

Это единственная страница в интернете с такой информацией. Больше я не нашёл аналогов не только в русскоязычном сегменте но и во всём интернете. Все остальные предлагают использовать WebRTC в большинстве своём не понимая что это такое и теряют возможность как либо контролировать данные, т.е. изменять их или записывать

**Возможно** мне сейчас скажут, что такой способ будет иметь задержку. Да, я не сказал, но мой проект в первую очередь рассчитан на 1 спикера и большого количества слушателей, поэтому задержка будет даже плюсом